# Upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 does not work

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I attempting to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04.

I first trued to follow the instructions in the release notes for jimmy jellyfish. After clicking on 'upgrade' nothing happens, irrespective of which of the two methods listed there I attempted.
Here, in help, I found an entry that told me to try /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk , which I did, and was told to install updates before upgrading. Again in help I found a reference that told me to try apt list --upgradable, and then the same command wi -a. Here I was told that and upgraded version of python was available, so I tried apt full-upgrade and received error messages.

PLEASE NOTE that I have very little familiarity with system commands (and I cannot see well, so the small script int the terminal is troublesome to read). I would like to be able to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 from my desktop by simply clicking on a few instructions.

FEEDBACK on attempts

The sidebar on this page says not to use edit to reply, but Mr./Ms. says to use 'edit'. I cannot figure out any other way to reply, so here goes:

I ran the ... `sudo apt upgrade` ... as instructed in step 2 of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417461/558158), and got the result: ...The following packages have been kept back:... ... `dh-python`...

Not knowing if that meant it went fine or not, I assumed that it went fine, and continued ith steps 3 to 5. At the end of that process I got the message: ... `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading`....

What is 'dh-python' and how can I release it or may I delete it?

Comment: We can really only help you with error messages when you paste them for us to advice you what to do. Currently I can only tell you to read & action those error messages, as you need to apply all upgrades before you can `do-release-upgrade` (using that or an alternate command) successfully. A reboot after full-upgrade (before *release-upgrading* maybe needed too).

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade should be done on a fully updated and healthy system.

1. Although the installer can usually cope with third party PPA's, you may have better luck disabling any third party PPA's, to bring your system as much as possible to "standard" before upgrading.
2. Update your system first with the command:

   ```
   sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. If that went fine, do a `dist-upgrade`, which will ensure that any obsolete packages will be removed (including the applications you may still have had that depended on them):

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```
4. Do not have the upgrader bother with installed packages that are not actually in use, so autoremove these first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
5. Only if all of this went smoothly and without issue, do the upgrade.

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and detailed answer. I do not see how I can add a full reply in detail as to what went on

Comment: This is a general answer on the conditions for upgrade. You can add details about what happened on your system in your question, using "Edit". Indeed that may allow to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

Comment: "Edit" means: "editing" your own question to add information or clarity.